# LWC javascript flatten object

Tags: lightning-web-components

Helo all,

In LWC, I am trying to flat the object with multilevel using resuable js function based on below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333126/how-to-flatten-an-object-with-nested-objects-in-javascript
Below JS code works fine expect for one scenario when two inner object has same structure &name. Only one object is copied.

Please look for enrollment2 in below examples, either object "test4" or "test5" flattened. How to flatten both objects and also  how to differentiate the name of that flattenedobject. Can someone help to solve this issue?

```
var enrollment = {
user: {
    id: 'string',
    name: 'string'
},
finished: 'boolean',
path: 'boolean'
}

var enrollment2 = {
user: {
    id: 'string',
    name: 'string'
},
test: {
    test1: {
        test2: {
            val0:'val0',
            test4: { //3rd level nested object for example
                val1: 'val1',
                val2: 'val2'
            },
             test5: { //4rd level nested object for example
                val1: 'val1',
                val2: 'val2'
            }
        }
    }
},
finished: 'boolean',
path: 'boolean'
}

var enrollment3 = {
user: {
    id: 'string',
    name: 'string'
},
test: {
    test1: {
        test2: {
            val0:'val0',
            test4: { //3rd level nested object for example
                val1: 'val1',
                val2: 'val2'
            }
        }
    }
},
finished: 'boolean',
path: 'boolean'
}

const flat = (obj, out) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
            out = flat(obj[key], out) //recursively call for nesteds
        } else {
            out[key] = obj[key] //direct assign for values
        }

    })
    return out
}

console.log(flat(enrollment, {}))
console.log(flat(enrollment2, {}))
console.log(flat(enrollment3, {}))
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? The code you're using seems to be working as designed, but there's more work to do to define the expected outcome and then build code to suite that outcome.

Comment: @DavidReed, Thanks for comment. I have explained the expected outcome on second paragraph where I have suck with.